# Do I need to change older HTML to new HTML5 standards?

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser, html-table

So say I have a website that was built using tables and specifically width tags (Awful I know). According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_width.asp) that website isn't using HTML5 because the width is no longer supported. My question is would I need to change that code, because it wouldn't be supported by modern day browsers? Or perhaps because it won't be supported later down the road?

Comment: If you specify your doctype correctly as the the one you are using, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

That all depends on what browsers you want your site to support. However, as a practical matter most browsers are going to be backward compatible for a while. Most modern browsers still support very early versions of HTML going back to the mid 90's.

That said, it is always a good idea to make sure you are setting the `doctype` tag on the page appropriately so the browser knows what it is getting and can accommodate it.

Answer (score 2):

There never was a width tag in HTML. For some elements, the `width` *attribute* can be used. There is no change in browser support to it; HTML5 drafts *require* browsers to support legacy attributes even though those drafts declare them as obsolete. W3schools is unreliable and misleading; see [w3fools](http://w3fools.com).

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule I would say no. I haven't read the spec or anything but it sounds like the width tag is being depreciated on tables?

If this site was intended to last 6-7 years without major changes then maybe you might want to futureproof it but it seems rather unlikely that the browser venders will break support any time soon. Too much of the web would be broken.